# How can I install Safari, without a browser or itunes access?

Tags: mobile-safari

I do not seem to have Safari on my iPhone 4.  I also do not seem to have iTunes installed, or any access to iTunes.  I have tried resetting my home-screen layout, but Safari and itunes still are not there.

I have tried to download the Safari install file to my PC, hoping to somehow transfer it to my iPhone.  But iTunes will not give up the file because I do not have iOS installed on the PC.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: What iOS? Is it Jailbroken? What version iTunes?

Comment: Is Safari disabled in **Settings > General > Restrictions** ? http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/01/how-to-hide-youtube-safari-and-other-default-app-icons-in-ios-5/

Comment: Graham Miln, thank you very much!  Yes, that was exactly the problem.  I had never changed any of the Restrictions settings myself, so I didn't even know to look there.  I am obviously very ignorant of how to use this phone!  And I'm very grateful for your help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Graham Miln suggested, it is most likely set this way in restrictions, assuming your phone isn't jail broken. Go to **Settings -> General -> Restrictions** and enable safari.

There is no way to install or uninstall Safari on an iOS device - it is a part of the operating system, nor is it possible to "have iOS installed on the PC"